# Repopulate MVC DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the view

We have a simple search text box and button

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputLoginSearch">Search for HOA</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 358px;">
            <input id="inputLoginSearch" runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter search phrase" style="width: 100%;" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="SearchButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-info" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and a DropDownList

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm" id="HOAListDiv">
    @Using (Ajax.BeginForm(Nothing, "Home/SelectFromHOAList", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST"}, New With {.id = "CategoryForm"}))
        @<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Please select the property</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.Connection_ID, Model.HOAList, New With {.id = "inputHOAList", .class = "form-control"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    End Using
</div>
```

The search button fires this script

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function () {
    var vData = $('#inputLoginSearch').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadHOAList", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { HOAName: $('#inputLoginSearch').val() },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        }
    });
});
```

The controller initially loads the list

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim vHOAModal As New HomeModel
    vHOAModal.HOAList = ReturnHOAList("xxxxx")
    Return View(vHOAModal)
End Function
```

... and the search button fires this

```
Function LoadHOAList(HOAName As String) As ActionResult
    Try
        ReturnedRows = 0
        If HOAName.Length < 3 Then
            Return Modal(ModalValidation("You must enter at least three letters!"))
        Else
            ModelState.Clear()
            Dim vHOAModal As New HomeModel
            vHOAModal.HOAList = ReturnHOAList(HOAName)
            If ReturnedRows = 0 Then
                Return Modal(ModalValidation(HOAName & " returned zero results!"))
            Else
                Return View(vHOAModal)
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex, 24, PageName)
        Return Modal(ModalError(ex.ToString))
    End Try
End Function


Private Function ReturnHOAList(SearchText) As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Try
        Dim vList As New List(Of SelectListItem)()
        vList.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = 0, .Text = "Select Property", .Selected = True})
        strSQL = "SELECT Connection_ID, HOA_Name FROM HOA_Connections WHERE Connection_ID != 4 AND HOA_Name LIKE '%" & SearchText & "%' ORDER BY HOA_Name ASC"
        Using DS As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, 0, True)
            For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                vList.Add(New SelectListItem With {.Value = Row("Connection_ID"), .Text = Row("HOA_Name")})
                ReturnedRows += 1
            Next
        End Using
        Return vList
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex, 43, PageName)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I have tried a number of ways but the DropDownList is not re-populating with the changed data. It is certainly being returned from the DB and populating the list...

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: If `HOAName.Length < 3` or if there is an exception, then you never call the method to populate the `SelectList`. But your making an ajax call, so why replace it anyway? In any case you do not do anything with the data your return (in the `success` callback code) And why are you using `ModelState.Clear()` - there is nothing in `ModelState`. And why are you mixing `Ajax.BeginForm()` and `$.ajax()`?

Comment: Stephen - 1. If the length is less than three,  or an exception we don't want to populate the list. If the name is a blank it will return every record and that would be thousands. 2. Can we populate from a success callback? How would that work? Assumed that changing the backend list in the Model would do that. 3. ModelState.Clear() just one of the things I tried. 4. Mix and match - just about tried every combination today

Comment: You have just shown a whole lot of code (much of which does not make a lot of sense) without actually explaining what you wanting to do. My best guess if that you want to display a filtered partial view of records based on the value of your search text and display that in the DOM? In which case you call a method that returns partial view and update the DOM with that partial view - e.g. `success: function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); }`, or you return a `JsonResult` containing the data you want and use that to update the DOM.

Comment: Its not even clear what you want to update - is it just the options in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Perhaps look at the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - its for populating a 2nd dropdownlist based on a value in the 1st - in your case it would be based on the value in the search text

Comment: Looked at the Fiddle. I'm guessing that I need to change the function to return data instead of updating the view? The jQuery.ajax is returning 'Internal Server Error' for the error: function

Comment: A `500 (Internal Server Error)` means the code in your controller method is throwing an exception (and I have no idea what `Modal` is in `Return Modal(...)`)

Comment: I can iterate though the code in debug, and it doesn't hit an exception. The modal is just a pop-up. Also any exceptions are emailed but it's only the jQuery that is throwing the toys out

Comment: Using your fiddle and return Json it now works. If you want to enter that as the answer I can mark it up. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154633/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-gchq).